# Функция mail() работает через раз

Tags: php, email

На сервере есть такой скрипт:

```
<?php 
  $Name = $_POST['name'];
  $Phone = $_POST['telephone'];
  $Mail = $_POST['mail'];

  $dateNow = date("Y-m-d");

  $message = "
  Заявка
  Имя: ".htmlspecialchars($Name)."
  Телефон: ".htmlspecialchars($Phone)."
  Почта: ".htmlspecialchars($Mail);

  mail("my@mail.ru", "Заявка", $message);
?>
```

Я ему методом POST с html страницы отдаю данные (name, mail...). Он отправляет на почту. Если я передам в качестве параметров name: Проверка, mail: Проверка. Он не отправит сообщение. А если name: Проверка 2, mail: Проверка 2. То отправит.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Что такое "не отправит"? Функция вернет false или письмо не достигнет получателя?

Comment: А точно больше нет отличий между успешными и неуспешными? Логи sendmail надо смотреть

Comment: Не отправил, значит функция возвращает true, а письмо не приходит.